# Android Web browser like Opera Desktop with M2 and extensions

Tags: android, web-browser

I'm looking for an Android web browser like the very old desktop Opera Browser with M2

**Must-haves:**

- Ability to save and load bookmarks to local user file
- Ability to save and load tabs to local user file.
- Ability to save and load sessions to local user file.
- Maybe Ability to save and load history to local user file.
- Ability to rearrange tabs
- Extensions.
- Notes.
- In the browser. Or extensions.

**Nice-to-have:**

- Maybe word processing.
- Maybe email
- Maybe Usenet
- Maybe news feeds
- Maybe web page and website creation and content management system.
- Maybe ability to host a web site.

A lot of these things, Opera desktop did around the end of the decade before last.

Comment: I don't know if such an app exists; but for starters, you could skim my Android app listing of [Web Browsers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_webbrowser) while waiting for (other) good recommendations.

Comment: Thank you Izzy.  I'm asking instead of, while sick, and actually dieing, passing by tens of hours going through listings.  I'm doing much better at the moment, but don't have time to data mine everything, especially as we don't have deterministic search engines anymore.

Comment: Well, you don't have to. It was just a pointer to where to look while waiting for possible answers. Best wishes for your health, which is of course much more important!